# When i click button ? Inserted value in edittext should be total and Calculate to display in another edittext with the help SELECT QUERY?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

All inserted in PaymentPaid(editText)  value should be sum and display to totalamt(Edittext).
 '

Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    try {

                String sql= Select-------?
        String amntpaid=PaymentPaid.getText().toString();       
        String totamnt=totalamt.getText().toString();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            });`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.......

```
 int subtotal = 0;
 int total =0;
 Cursor  cursor = dh.rawQuery("SELECT _column_name FROM table_name WHERE _column_name LIKE ? ", new String[] {"%"});
if(cursor.moveToFirst())   
            do{

    subtotal = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_column_name"));
                total = total+subtotal;
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
     total_show_edttxt.setext(total);
```

Comment: This is not work sir !!..actully i am using h2 database..db file...i am using jdbc..